# Azure mysql virtual machine stops working after a while

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.net Web API deployed on azure and I also have there a MySql database in separate virtual machine running on linux. The problem I have is that when I restart the database and redeploy the web API from visual studio the connection  between web API and mySql is working fine but after like 30 minutes I get this error:

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

If I want to make it work again i have to restart the virtual machine with database and redeploy the web API from visual studio. I am using connection string like this to connect in my web config

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=publicIpAddress;Port=3306;Database=db_12345_db;Uid=user;Pwd=*********;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

This connection was working on server we had before we switched to azure. I suspect I did not configure azure correctly.

Any idea how to fix this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

### Connections Dropped

When connecting to a Azure SQL Database, idle connections may be terminated by a network component (such as a firewall) after a period of inactivity. There are two types of idle connections, in this context:

- Idle at the TCP layer, where connections can be dropped by any number
  of network devices.
- Idle by the SQL Azure Gateway, where TCP keepalive messsages might be occurring (making the connection not idle from a TCP perspective), but not had an active query in 30 minutes. In this scenario, the Gateway will determine that the TDS connection is idle at 30 minutes and terminate the connection.

https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/316 
Hope this works for you.

Comment: The OP isn't using SQL Database service. They're running MySQL in a VM.

Comment: Anyways are you keeping the connectivity idle for ~30 minutes?

Comment: The web api handles request from my iOS app and it happens that it is idle for ~ 30 min or sometimes more. How could I set it not to terminate the connection after time interval or to make a new connection when the termination occurs?

Comment: Let's not start a discussion here. Feel free to move this to Chat. Or ask a different question.